# Check if row exists, if not add it [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, insert

I need to add a row to a MySQL database table but only if the row doesn't already exist. My database server just went down so I can't test this, but will this work as expected?

```
INSERT INTO `blocks` (`block_file`,`settings_group`)
VALUES ('announcements','announcement_settings')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `block_file`,`settings_group`
                  FROM `blocks`
                  WHERE `block_file`='announcements' AND `settings_group`='announcement_settings')
```

It seems like sound logic. Is this a valid query or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: In SQL Server that type of approach would give you a race condition. Not sure whether this is true for MySQL as well. Is it just this specific query or do you always want to enforce uniqueness on those 2 columns?

Comment: Same with mysql - you cannot modify a table while you are selecting from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create UNIQUE index on `(block_file,settings_group)` columns, and MySQL will never let you insert a row that would duplicate these values.

And to answer the question: No, it will not work at all.

Comment: And if you need to insert several records, just use the IGNORE keyword, so if you try to insert a duplicate row, the error would be treated as warning. Check the sintax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/insert.html

Comment: Thanks! Works just as expected and much cleaner.